# using tr command to read permission

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tr

Following commands have been executed by me

```
[root@gblabvl31 Aakash]# cat > file1.txt
-rwx
[root@gblabvl31 Aakash]# cat file1.txt |tr '[-rwx]' '[0421]' > file2.txt
[root@gblabvl31 Aakash]# cat file2.txt
-]]]
```

I could not understand why the expected output which is

```
0421
```

is not achieved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr` is a little special and expects its parameters to already be character classes, thus

```
$ echo '-rwx' | tr -- '-rwx' '0421'
0421
```

yields the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the character class:

```
$ tr -- '-rwx' '0421' <<<'-rwx'
0421
```